# Hashover comments disappear

Tags: javascript, php, comments

When I was using hashover on my local website,the main frame was showed,but the comments was gone.Who can help me about this?

I used php5.3.10,apache2.2.10
I want to upload a image,but seems I don't have the reputation to finish this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.
The html-temple file needs to be rebuild